# Float on embed youtube video make it disappear

Tags: html, css, iframe

I want to put 2 divs inline. The first div is a video embed from youtube. The second div is with some text. I tried with float and clear but when I use this, the video disappear. I tried with display: inline-block but I received the same result. I tried with an empty div at the bottom with `clear:both`, the result wasn't happy. I really want to know where is the problem? The video container is responsive. Maybe this can cause the issue? I will attach a section of code below.

```css
.desc {
  border-left: 4px solid #80d4ff;
  padding: 6px 10px 8px 6px;
  text-indent: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.video-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.videoHndl {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoHndl">
  <div class="video-container">
    <iframe width="500px" height="280" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HRbD4UcK-0I">
            </iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="desc">
    <p><b>Description:</b></p>
    <p>Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do:

```css
.desc{
    margin-left: 500px;
    border: 1px black solid;
    border-left: 4px solid #80d4ff;
    padding: 6px 10px 8px 6px;
    text-indent: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.video-container {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 500px;
    height: 280px;
    border: 1px green solid;
}

 .videoHndl{
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px; /* to be updated to the desired height */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
   border: 1px blue solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoHndl">
    <div class="video-container">
        <iframe width="500px" height="280"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HRbD4UcK-0I">
        </iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="desc">
        <p><b>Description:</b></p>
        <p>Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text 
        Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some 
        text Some text Some text Some text </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This way is working but when I resize the browser,  the resposive isn't working. I should use @media query for this?

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` tag automatically takes a new line when rendered, you may want to try `<span>` tag instead

Comment: I changed the 'div' tag in to 'span' tag but the result is the same. Look at the picture attached below. https://imgur.com/a/qOhis

Answer (score 0):

You have to add width in pixel see below code, this code will help you for modifying your css.

```css
.desc {
  border-left: 4px solid #80d4ff;
  padding: 6px 10px 8px 6px;
  text-indent: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
}

.video-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 15px 0;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}

.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.videoHndl {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoHndl">
  <div class="video-container">
    <iframe width="300px" height="280" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HRbD4UcK-0I">
      </iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="desc">
    <p><b>Description:</b></p>
    <p>Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ankit, excuse me, can I ask you why did you use this values for width? I tried to change them and now is not working...

Comment: Without width, div will be full width automatically so we have to apply CSS width so float works

Answer (score 0):

Try this css code

```
.desc{
  border-left: 4px solid #80d4ff;
  padding: 6px 10px 8px 6px;
  text-indent: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.video-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 15px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
 .videoHndl{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-start;
 }
```

Comment: Your way works but when I resize the browser (to make it smaller like a screen for phone), this divs overlap and the responsive doesn't work.

Comment: Try to use @media query to make it responsive

Answer (score 0):

Its causing because of setting position to absolute for .video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed classes. Remove the parameter and set float: left for video handle and you will be able to see the two divs side by side. So your edited css should be like this.

```
.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
.videoHndl{
   max-width: 500px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
   float:left;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reponse but this isn't work for me. I attached below what happened with my #wrapper when i remove position absolute and insert a float:left into .videoHndl. https://imgur.com/a/koUxA